# There exist no continuous one one onto (Bijective ) function form $[0,1]$ $\to$ $[0,1]\times[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness, uniform-continuity

I wanted to prove that there exist no continuous one to one and onto function form $[0,1] \to [0,1]\times[0,1]$.
My attempt : image of f on $[0,1]$ , a compact set is again compact .$[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is also compact.
On contrary suppose there exist continuous one one onto function between $[0,1]\to [0,1]\times[0,1]$ then  its inverse function is also continuous one one onto. 
 Upto this I can write from given information 
 No idea how to proceed further .Any Help will be appreciated .

Comment: Everything you want to know is contained in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve).

Comment: @JanBohr it is not injective

Comment: I did not claim that. But the article discusses in detail why it cannot be injective under 'Properties'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such function because, since the domain is compact, it would be a homeomorphism.  But $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ are not homeomorphic: if you remove $\frac12$ from $[0,1]$, it becomes disconnected. But there is no such point in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Comment: Efficient one. However there must be some 1st year analysis way of doing this, I suspect...

Comment: @mol3574710n0fN074710n I suspect otherwise…